# How to serialize a JsonObject without too much quotes?

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm writing a small fluent wrapper over com.google.gson.JsonObject.

When I serialize my Json, I get:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"{\"innerKey\":\"value3\"}"}
```

How do I get rid of the redundant quotes?

My code:

```
public class JsonBuilder {
    private final JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    private final Map<String, JsonBuilder> children = newHashMap();

    public String toJson() {
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonBuilder> entry : children.entrySet()) {
            String value = entry.getValue().toJson();
            add(entry.getKey(), value);
        }
        children.clear();

        return json.toString();
    }

    public JsonBuilder add(String key, String value) {
        json.addProperty(key, value);
        return this;
    }

    public JsonBuilder add(String key, JsonBuilder value) {
        Preconditions.checkArgument(!children.containsKey(key));
        children.put(key, value);
        return this;
    }
}

String json = new JsonBuilder()
    .add("key1", "value1")
    .add("key2", "value2")
    .add("key3", new JsonBuilder()
        .add("innerKey", "value3"))
    .toJson();
```

Comment: That is json syntax, I dont think there is a way to disable it. any specific reason to remove them?

Comment: Underscore-java library has U.objectBuilder() and U.arrayBuilder() methods.

Comment: 1. `JsonObject header = new JsonObject();`
2. `header.addProperty("name", mimheader.getName());`
3. `header.toString();`

[com.google.gson.JsonObject Java Examples](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=com.google.gson.JsonObject)

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is that you've mixed String's and Object's in your `JsonBuilder` class. Rather stick as closely as possible to `JsonObject`, and only extend it ever so slightly. If you want to wrap a `JsonBuilder`, do it like this, with the smallest possible modification to `JsonObject`:

```
package com.craigmj.gson;

import java.util.HashMap;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

class JsonBuilder {
    public final JsonObject json = new JsonObject();

    public String toJson() {
        return json.toString();
    }

    public JsonBuilder add(String key, String value) {
        json.addProperty(key, value);
        return this;
    }

    public JsonBuilder add(String key, JsonBuilder value) {
        json.add(key, value.json);
        return this;
    }
}

public class GsonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(new JsonBuilder()
            .add("key1", "value1")
            .add("key2", "value2")
            .add("key3", new JsonBuilder()
            .add("innerKey", "value3"))
            .toJson());
    }

}
```

Note that I've made the `json` property public so that you can still use all the gson methods with it if you want the full gson functionality. (Of course, you should probably have a getter.) Unfortunately, one can't extends `JsonObject` since it is final.

Answer (score 1):

Use gson.toJsonTree() instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at this
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jr#writing-with-composers

Jackson jr is a compact alternative to full Jackson Databind component.