# ajax data retrieve values give me output as undefined

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I created a ajax cord for my jsp... The Sql query reterns many columns.. I want to add these columns in for loop and for loop works fine which is inside the ajax cors.but when jsp page load all values show as undefined . I cant guest that error.values succesfully pass to the jsp.I check it using postman and alert msg...

```
My model class is Product

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private long productId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int serialNo;

    private int slsiUnit;
    private String itemDesc;
    private int slsNo;
    private String hsCode;
    private String userId;

    public long getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(long productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public int getSerialNo() {
        return serialNo;
    }

    public void setSerialNo(int serialNo) {
        this.serialNo = serialNo;
    }

    public int getSlsiUnit() {
        return slsiUnit;
    }

    public void setSlsiUnit(int slsiUnit) {
        this.slsiUnit = slsiUnit;
    }

    public String getItemDesc() {
        return itemDesc;
    }

    public void setItemDesc(String itemDesc) {
        this.itemDesc = itemDesc;
    }

    public int getSlsNo() {
        return slsNo;
    }

    public void setSlsNo(int slsNo) {
        this.slsNo = slsNo;
    }

    public String getHsCode() {
        return hsCode;
    }

    public void setHsCode(String hsCode) {
        this.hsCode = hsCode;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Product{");
        sb.append("serialNo=").append(serialNo);
        sb.append(", slsiUnit=").append(slsiUnit);
        sb.append(", itemDesc='").append(itemDesc).append('\'');
        sb.append(", slsNo=").append(slsNo);
        sb.append(", hsCode='").append(hsCode).append('\'');
        sb.append(", userId='").append(userId).append('\'');
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

ajax cord is

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/restservice/ViewProduct',
                success: function (result) {
                    var jString = JSON.stringify(result);
                    var jdata = JSON.parse(jString);
                    alert(jString);
                    for (var x = 0; x < jdata.length; x++) {
                        var tr = "<tr>";
                        var td1 = "<td>" + jdata.itemDesc + "</td>";
                        var td2 = "<td>" + jdata.itemDesc + "</td>";
                        var td3 = "<td>" + jdata.serialNo + "</td>";
                        var td4 = "<td>" + jdata.serialNo + "</td>";
                        var td5 = "<td>" + jdata.serialNo + "</td></tr>";
                        $("#example2").append(tr + td1 + td2 + td3 + td4 + td5);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

When I added alert to the jString on my JSP all values views successfully. I want to map these values to table

Please help me.

Comment: Your String Builder is not building valid JSON. Try it here: https://jsonlint.com/ Probably use a JSON Builder in Java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876089/how-to-fluently-build-json-in-java

Comment: Ok thank you for your advice sir

Comment: building JSON by hand is completely unnecessary, all languages have tools to serialise objects into JSON for you, and avoid any silly syntax mistakes.