# How to create following JSON using JSONObject java?

Tags: java, json

I need to represent the following JSON structure using JSONObject in java. How can this be done?
I am confused because car is a JSON, brands is an array, which together combined become single element of 'CARS' array.

```
{
    cars: [{
            car: {},
            brands: ["C", "D"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Unclear what exactly you're confused by or what you're stuck on. Do you have some attempt to show?

Comment: Related: [How to fluently build JSON in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8876089)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear but if you just want an example of JSONObject then the code below can generate what you want.

```
JSONObject car = new JSONObject();
car.put("car", new JSONObject());

JSONArray brands = new JSONArray();
brands.put("C");
brands.put("D");
car.put("brands", brands);

JSONArray cars = new JSONArray();
cars.put(car);

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("cars", cars);

System.out.println(json.toString(2));
```

The output is

```
{
  "cars": [
    {
      "car": {},
      "brands": [
        "C",
        "D"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```