# Least boilerplaty way of creating JSON in Java/Spring Boot?

Tags: java, json

For example in rust, we can use type-safe [json! macro](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/macro.json.html) like this:-

```
let value = json!({
   "user": json!({
       "data" : json!({"
           filled": false
        })
    })
});
```

What is the similar way in java without creating POJO or string literal?

Comment: Possibly related: [How to fluently build JSON in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8876089)

Comment: @Pshemo its still so much boilerplate for such trivial task

Comment: You can also create String representing JSON and parse it. So something like `String jsonStr = "{your JSON structure}"; JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);`.

Comment: If the boilerplate is a significant issue for you then, assuming your requirements allow it, use a different language than Java. For instance, I would assume you can code a Spring Boot application using Kotlin (or even mix Kotlin and Java together).

Answer (score 0):

In spring, you normally don't need lines like your RUST-example. Spring is doing a lot behind the scenes for you.

## Two common use-cases

### 1. Provide a REST-API

Normally, when you use spring, then you want to build a REST-API. A simple API looks like this:

```java
// User.java
@Data // <- Lombok annotation, which creates getter/setter/equals/hashcode for us
public class User {
   private String name;
}

// UserController.java
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

   private final UserRepository userRepository;

   @GetMapping("/{id}")
   public User getUser(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
      // spring will serialize the user automatically for you
      // there is no need to build a json yourself
      return userRepository.getById(id);
   }
```

### 2. Consume a REST-API

On the other hand, we want to consume a REST-API. But also here: Spring and his ecosystem is doing the JSON-part for you.

```java
// User.java
@Data
public class User {
    private String name;
}

// some random method in a class with a webClient
private User consumeRest() {
   // even here: no manual json parsing at all
   // Spring-magic is working for you
   return this.webClient.get()
      .uri(someUriHere)
      .retrive()
      .bodyToMono(User.class)
      .block();
}
```

## tl;dr

Spring (and java) requires a strong typing. You need almost always a type-class (aka POJO). The classes can be really complex. Hundred of fields and nested fields? No problem.

There are some "hacks" to bypass the type. Like the link in the comments or a `Map<String, Object>` but you will loose the type-safety.

If that is too much "boilerplate", than Java is not perhaps the right choice for you.