# want to parse my json file and return some specific values as json object in java

Tags: java, json

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class Task2 {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException {
        JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
        Object ob =jp.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\z033055\\Downloads\\details.json"));
        JSONObject jo =(JSONObject) ob;
        boolean success = (boolean)jo.get("success");
        System.out.println("success:"+success);
        JSONObject csrf= (JSONObject)jo.get("csrf");
        String value =(String)csrf.get("value");
        System.out.println("value:"+value);
        JSONArray data =(JSONArray)jo.get("data");
        for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++) {
            JSONObject jdata=(JSONObject)data.get(i);
            String id=(String)jdata.get("id");
            System.out.println("id:"+id);
            String type=(String)jdata.get("type");
            System.out.println("type:"+type);
            String identifier =(String)jdata.get("identifier");
            System.out.println("identifier:"+identifier);
            String cestamp=(String)jdata.get("cestamp");
            System.out.println("cestamp:"+cestamp);
        }
    }
    




}
```

I want to my output to be a jsonobject

current output:

```
success:true
value:MLGY-SWOI-GHDD-LEDF-TSO7-JV8X-XIEC-0TQ5
id:B65C2473BE580000622048BE000EEC0B
type:ECUParameterValueInteger__36e72ec09f5d4b9ba4e6da8d8d393941
identifier:B65C2473BE580000622048BE000EEC0B
cestamp:B65C2473BE580000622051FB001D83E0
```

want like this

```
{
    "statusCode":"",
    "value":"",
    "data": [{
        "id": "B65C2473BE580000622048BE000EEC0B",
        "type": "ECUParameterValueInteger__36e72ec09f5d4b9ba4e6da8d8d393941",
        "identifier": "B65C2473BE580000622048BE000EEC0B",
        "cestamp": "30B841C5DC52000062468FC2001202DA"
    } ]

},
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you want your output to be. I don't see anywhere in your code where you attempt to create a new JSON object or to modify the existing JSON object? Hint: One easy solution is to construct a new `JSONObject` and simply use the relevant methods to insert the elements you want into it, eg `yourNewJSON.put("name", value);`

Comment: @sorifiend i have  updated the question .. with the expected output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fluently build JSON in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876089/how-to-fluently-build-json-in-java)

Comment: @sorifiend no dude . i'm getting error

Comment: Well what is the error, and what code did you use? We can't help if you don't provide details. That method works for everyone else, it should work for you too.